# SonarQube code smell does not work for a constructor, but does work for another constructor in an inner class in the same file

Tags: java, sonarqube

I have a rule that methods should not have too many parameters (maximum 5), code smells code does not appears in a class for a constructor with more than 5 parameters.
But appears for methods that have more than 5 parameters in the same class, and for inner static class with more than 5 parameters.
What the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about the rule java:S107.

You can edit the rule in SonarQube to have different thresholds for methods and for constructors:

Parameter for max number of method parameters:

> max - (Default Value: 7)

Parameter for max number of constructor parameters:

> constructorMax - (Default Value: 7)

So please check if you have different values set for the parameters of this rule.

As for why it is not checked for constructors of an inner class, maybe SonarQube uses the parameter max instead of constructorMax for a constructor of an inner class. But I could not find anything related to inner classes in the description of the rule.

Comment: I checked the values of the method and constructor parameters, everything is fine there (for methods 5 and for constructors 5). I started researching this issue and for some reason the bad smell of sonarQube code doesn't work for the code from the previous commit as I add new constructors or methods with more than 5 parameters to the new commit - sonarQube notes this issue.